# VBA - Very new to VBA Struggling to filter a piviot table .pivotitems based on a cell containing a time and date

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and have hit a wall. I am trying automate the use of 15 pivot tables (Only one test one in this example) When i do this manually I enter a  "mm/yyyy" into the pivot search box and getting a return of the items from a given month. (As seen in the screenshot)

The following code filters correctly if I focus on the Letter column or number column but if I try and focus on the case creation time / formatted date I get "Unable to get the pivotitem property of the pivotfield class"

I assume this is because the date and time are combined or because the data is not "Clean".

Any very basic pointers you can give are welcome.

Thanks

Code:

```
Sub DateFilterPivotWithSlicer()

Dim p_i As PivotItem

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields ("FormattedDate")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("FormattedDate")
        .PivotItems("24/08/2018").Visible = True
        For Each p_i In .PivotItems
            ' If loop here will cycle through all items in the pivot table and then pass to next
            If p_i.Name <> "24/08/2018" Then
            p_i.Visible = False

            End If
        Next
    End With


End Sub
```

Test Data I am working with:
[image: Test Data I am working with]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub DateFilterPivotWithSlicer()

Dim p_i As PivotItem
Dim pv As PivotTable
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim sFind As String, s As String
Dim d As Long

Set Ws = ActiveSheet

Set pv = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
'Set pv = Ws.PivotTables(1)
pv.ClearAllFilters

    With pv.PivotFields("FormattedDate")
        sFind = "08/2018"
        sFind = Replace(sFind, "/", "-")

        For Each p_i In .PivotItems
            s = p_i.Name
                d = DateValue(p_i.Name)
                s = Format(d, "mm/yyyy") 's result 08-2018
            ' If loop here will cycle through all items in the pivot table and then pass to next
            If s = sFind Then
                p_i.Visible = True
            Else
                p_i.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this did not appear to work. 1004 - unable to set the visivle property of the Pivotitem class -   p_i.Visible = False

Comment: At least 1 pivotitem MUST always remain visible! If neither of your `If s = sFind` succeds, you`ll try to switch them all invisible, and get the error on the last pivotitem. So you need e. g. two loops, where the first loop checks, if at least 1 pivotitem fulfils the criteria, and then in a second loop you switch all others invisible.